# How to create custom functionalities on submit to a webform

Tags: form-submit, drupal-8, drupal-webform

I am new with Drupal 8 coding and I need some guidance on how to create custom web form with your own submit functionalities that checks in the db with all field match and redirects to another page.

I have tried creating the form but i do not know how to start with creating own submit operation.

I have name, email and case fields in my form with submit button and my db is dr-sp-students with column id,name,email,case

Answer (score 0):

Try the remote post handler. It can be found under:

> webform -> settings -> email / handlers.